# How do you set-up both a daily (nightly) build and continuous integration?

Tags: tfs

How do you set-up both a daily (nightly) build and continuous integration?

I've created a CI build in Visual Studio, but the trigger is only one of options, but I want both a CI and a scheduled nightly build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clone that CI Build Definition and change the Trigger condition.

Comment: DOH ... I'd got stuck on trying to get my single build to do both ... ta

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the [new build system](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/vs/define-build), you can create multiple triggers.

Comment: Shame, we're using an on-premise TFS 2013 ... that looks to be Visual Studio Team Services (aka VSO)

Comment: @SteveC It's also in TFS 2015.